# how to make global string declaration

Tags: c++

In a C++ Win32 program I need to use the same string variable in the modules

main.cpp and client.cpp. Both main.cpp and client.cpp have a #include client.h

where I try to declare the global(extern) string.

Let us call the string "test_string"

How do I declare the string as global so I can use it in both modules?

Hope the question is clear enough.

Comment: Not a duplicate, the answer in the link won't work for Windows. You need to export the global variable with `declspec` for this to work in Windows. Edit: Although if it is only for multiple files and not dlls, then extern will work.

Comment: the examles in the other questions declare int, that is working OK in my program, but the how do I do it for strings? I can't get it to work

Comment: @user1288615 when you say string do you mean a `std::string` or a c-string?

Comment: "I can't get it to work" is not enough information. Please provide the full error message and the minimum code to reproduce it.

Comment: I mean a std::string

Comment: Then it should work exactly the same.  If it does not please provide a [mcve]

Comment: This is the error meassage I get from the compiler:    error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'test_string'
error C2371: 'test_string': redefinition; different basic types
 note: see declaration of 'test_string'

Comment: i use extern string  test_string;  which is the cause of the problem

Comment: but, what do I need to use instead of extern string test_string?